# Drawing 3D elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, geometry

My application returns the relative positions between two lines and I want draw this lines with Javascript. The line is defined with a director vector, a point and is **three dimension**. 
Is there any library available which can do this? I found only [Victor.js](http://victorjs.org/) but does not help in my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Three.js](http://threejs.org/): "The aim of the project is to create a lightweight 3D library with a very low level of complexity — in other words, for dummies. The library provides canvas, svg, CSS3D and WebGL renderers."
- [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/): "Processing.js is the sister project of the popular Processing visual programming language, designed for the web. Processing.js makes your data visualizations, digital art, interactive animations, educational graphs, video games, etc. work using web standards and without any plug-ins."

Both are very mature and have an active community. There are plenty of resources to learn from, for example [three.js's *Getting Started*](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) and [Processing.js's *Learning*](http://processingjs.org/learning/).

Comment: Would suggest looking at [p5.js](https://p5js.org/), which has largely superseded Processing.js since this answer, and includes methods for handling three dimensional vectors.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/programming-3d-shapes/a/what-are-3d-shapes), you have a really easy guide to draw a 3D shape on a 2D surface (With ProcessingJS)
*Its a guide by Khan Academy to make 3D shapes with ProcessingJS*

You might want to read [THIS](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/3D-tutorial) too.
*Its the original article, by Peter Collingridge*
**Draw 3d shapes on html5 canvas**